# Selectioncolor doesn't work within KeyPress event

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, selection, keypress

I'm trying to change the color of some text when Ctrl+Z is pressed as the following:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z && (e.Control))
    {
        if (undoList.Count > 0)
        {
            ignoreChange = true;
            richTextBox1.Text = undoList[undoList.Count - 1];
            //richTextBox1.Focus();
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 3;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 2;

            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
            undoList.RemoveAt(undoList.Count - 1);

            ignoreChange = false;
        }   
    }
}
```

However, the selected text won't change its color. It would stay highlighted. I threw in the same logic in a Click event and it worked. Also, if I take out `ichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;` everything works expectedly. Not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _richTextBox1.Text = undoList[undoList.Count - 1];_ You must not change the `Text` directly  if you want to have/keep any formatting. If you want to manage an undolist it will have to contain the position as well as the text and the formatting..Instead set/change `rtb.SelectedText` !! - As for the differences you noted: they may come from the ^Z being processed in addition to your code. set `e.Handled = true` to prevent that !

Comment: @TaW It worked after adding e.Handled to signal ^Z is done! Thank you very much.

Comment: Good, however, do mind my wanrnings about changing the Text directly! Sooner or later it'll fail.

Comment: @TaW I will definitely keep that in mind. I now use Rtf instead of Text to keep the formatting and it works well so far. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to handle a command key (<kbd>Control</kbd>) and that won't happen in a standard `KeyPress` event. To do that you have to override `ProcessCmdKey` method on your form.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control|Keys.Z))
    {
        if (undoList.Count > 0)
        {
            ignoreChange = true;
            richTextBox1.Text = undoList[undoList.Count - 1];
            //richTextBox1.Focus();
            richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 3;
            richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 2;

            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
            undoList.RemoveAt(undoList.Count - 1);

            ignoreChange = false;

            // Do not handle base method
            // which will revert the last action
            // that is changing the selection to green.
            return true;
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem I was experiencing wasn't because the control key wasn't detected. It was because ctrl+Z was still process in addition to the logic I had within the KeyPress event. The problem was solved by setting e.Handled to true to indicate the KeyPress event was handled.  I was wondering if it's a rule of thumb to use ProcessCmdKey instead of KeyPress event when dealing with the Ctrl key?

Comment: I would say it's a method you override when building custom keyboard shortcuts. But I'm happy to be corrected if this assumption is an incorrect one.